# ASP.NET How to get the authenticated user password when logged using a client certificate?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, ssl, client-certificates

I'm migrating to client certificate authentication instead of windows basic authentication for my ASP.NET Web App. I've set user mapping in IIS 6.0 correctly and now I have a client certificate installed and mapped to a specific AD server account. I can login to the website using the installed certificate correctly and I can retrieve the mapped username correctly using Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].
The problem is that I still need to retrieve the mapped user password however when I tried to use Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_PASSWORD"] it returns blank string?
Any ideas how to get the mapped user password correctly?

Comment: I believe you can't. If the user is authenticated with a certificate and the password is not involved how you'd expect it to be available to your code at the server? What's the reason you need it, anyway? It sounds like you are trying to do something you shouldn't do or there possibly is another way to do this.

Comment: I'd expect it to be available because simply Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] is available. I need it because the user needs to be authenticated to his Mailbox via IMAP connection further.

Comment: Just because you can see the username doesn't mean it's going to store the password. In fact, you should never store passwords in memory except to perform login, and that should be hashed.